# What is the ASP.Net equivalent to PHP's Echo?

Tags: php, asp.net, echo

I want to 'echo' a string separated by delimeters like:
sergio|tapia|1999|10am

the Body of an HTML page.

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`Response.Write(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585.aspx).

There are a couple of shortcuts to `Response.Write` if you are trying to output on the page:

```
<%="sergio|tapia|1999|10am"%>
```

Or

```
<%:"sergio|tapia|1999|10am"%> (.NET 4.0)
```

See [here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx) for the different options.

Comment: For example say I response.write() twice. Are the both string output in separate lines? Or are they in a single html tag?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia - Depends where you output each one. Can't really tell you without seeing some code.

Comment: Sergio, just try it. However, to create multiple lines you would need to add a `"\n"` at the end, and to make things show up on separate lines, consider using `<br/>`.

Comment: @Sergio Using `Response.Write` twice will place the second string right after the first with no line break. `Response.Write("Hello")` followed by `Response.Write("World")` will output "HelloWorld".

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Used it to force the client side browser to update style sheet everytime. Thank you so much good sir!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Response.Write(str)` both in code-behind and on the .ASPX page:

```
<%
Response.Write(str)
%>
```

Using `Response.Write()` in code-behind places the string before the HTML of the page, so it's not always useful.

You can also create a server control somewhere on your ASPX page, such as a label or literal, and set the text or value of that control in code-behind:

.ASPX:

```
<asp:Label id="lblText" runat="server" />
```

Code-behind:

```
lblText.Text = "Hello world"
```

Outputs in HTML:

```
<span id="lblText">Hello World</span>
```

If you don't want `<span>`s added, use a literal:

```
<asp:Literal id="litText" runat="server" />
```

And set the value attribute of the literal instead of the text attribute:

```
litText.Value = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the new Razor syntax, you can just write @variable in your html and its value will be echoed:

```
@{
    var name = 'Hiccup';
}

<p>Welcome @name</p>
```