# Is there an equivalent of echo in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a php code which I have converted to asp.net code. The PHP code simply echoes a response which a client reads and interpretes, however in asp.net, the generated output is forced to be in html format -- which is precisely because I'm using asp.net labels to print the output.

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing as the echo in php or is there a very lightweight code that can help me parse the html text properly?

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to do is like

> //get post data
>
> echo "Some stuff"

My current testing aspx file *is*:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="grabber.aspx.cs" Inherits="qProcessor.grabber" %>
```

and the code behind has just one method:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Response.Write("Welcome!");
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have for ASP.net code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ASP.Net equivalent to PHP's Echo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977675/what-is-the-asp-net-equivalent-to-phps-echo)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The one-for-one equivalent would be [`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx):

```
Response.Write("some text");
```

That said, ASP .NET and PHP are very different frameworks. With ASP .NET (including the MVC framework) there is rarely a need to write directly to the response stream in this manner.

One such case would be if you wanted to return a very lightweight response. You could do something like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write("<root someAttribute = 'value!' />");
```

Any method *other* than using `Response` directly can (and probably will) alter the output. So in short - if you want to just dump raw data into the `HttpResponse`, you'll want to use `Response.Write()`.

Comment: I keep getting this error when I try this: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." What could be the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Hard to say without seeing your code sample. Probably best to make it another question. If you do, include the relevant code and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your consice and explanatory answer, do you know what could be the cause though? Check the question update for code...

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Given your example you really shouldn't be using `Response.Write` in the first place.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10319985/1159478) I show you how ASP expects you to solve this problem.

Comment: @Yuck I don't know what the heck happened but I just came back from somewhere and it's working fine now. Yes indeed, I'm looking for the lightest response possible as it's a mobile stuff and low bandwidth is heavy consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Response.Write("");`

or in your .aspx page use `<%="string"%>`

Comment: And with .NET 4.0 `<%:%>` which adds HTML encoding.

Comment: Those tags don't write directly to the response stream, though. It's very similar to but not exactly the same as `echo` and `Response.Write()`. Especially with `<%: ... %>` which will do smart HTML encoding before pumping the value into the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can write any text you want to the client:

```
Response.Write(yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned by Yuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319576/1159478) you really don't need to use `Response.Write` (which is the direct port of echo) in ASP most of the time.  Given your example, you probably want to do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Server.HTMLEncode("<h1>Welcome!</h1>")));
    //will actually print <h1>Welcome!</h1>, rather than Welcome! that's bolded/centered/etc.
}
```

Or you could even add the literal control, label, etc. to the markup, and then just set the `Text` property in the code behind.  That's the standard approach for solving this issue in an ASP environment.

Comment: that's what I'm doing but the response ends up having output in html format.

Comment: What *should* the response type be?  I added an HTMLEncode method do that you could, for example, write out tags and have them displayed as text rather than as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I figured out the problem was some computerized misbehaviour but it's all working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.Write()` for that:

```
Response.Write("your text here");
```