# How to make a echo command in a C# Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, echo

So, I am making a hacking game, and in it you control a terminal. So far, I have done 'help' and 'cls' commands, that don't require parameters. But, for say a echo command, I need the computer to detect the keyword 'echo' and the rest of the text as what you want to 'echo'. How can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319531/is-there-an-equivalent-of-echo-in-asp-net-c-sharp) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something line this:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine(); //You might have this already in your code

if (input.StartsWith("echo "))
{
    var text = input.Substring(5);

    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

This checks to see if the input line starts with `echo`, and if it does, it prints to the console whatever is after the first 5 characters (which is the length of `echo` and one space)

Comment: Thanks Man! That worked great! You might have just saved my project :D