# How to display HTML content in C# string?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
string html = @"Hello <b> World ! </b>";
```

The desired output would be

> Hello **World !**

The string html can be used anywhere on label, textbox, etc.

But it is not working. It just displays as it is `Hello <b> World ! </b>`

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I don't think it's related as that link is to handle **Bold** only but OP is asking something dynamically if I'm not wrong

Comment: Are you doing this in a WinForms application? WPF? ASP.Net? This is quite important to know if we are to help you :-)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977675/what-is-the-asp-net-equivalent-to-phps-echo

Comment: What is not working ? - what error do you get, or you can not find the string ?

Comment: I dont want this string to be placed on only web form.. want to use this string on different places like on label, or on textbox, or inside a dynamic table etc

Comment: @Aristos Please see the updates

Comment: Some asp.net controls have the htmlEncode render by default and you need to disable it, or change control.

Comment: you can do this : <% Response.Write("Hello <b> World ! </b>") %>

Answer (score 1):

Try `HtmlString` like:

```
HtmlString html = new HtmlString("Hello <b> World ! </b>");
```

Comment: I cannot find HtmlString in C#

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: And why the negative vote? I just tested it in an asp.net mvc 4 application and it works fine.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I don't think this question is related to MVC.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN It works in web forms too, I just tested it. Can you show me some example code like how you are planning to use it? The following code works for me (lbl is a `<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>`): `HtmlString html = new HtmlString("Hello <b> World ! </b>"); lbl.Text = html.ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.Raw()`

```
@Html.Raw(string);
```

See here for more: http://forums.asp.net/t/1903975.aspx?how+to+use+html+raw

Comment: The OP really want MVC?

Comment: Oh sorry, I generelly use MVC if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of ASP.NET, but your safest bet is to create a literal control

```
<asp:Literal runat='server' id='yourOutput' Text='' />
```

And then set it on code behind

```
yourOutput.Text = html;
```

This should work on all versions of *classic* ASP.NET - for MVC projects you already got good answers.

Comment: As I already said.. I want this string to put on different controls not onlyin literal