# Is there anything like "echo" of PHP in asp.net?

Tags: php, html, css, asp.net, echo

When i work in some code in PHP, i generaly implant html through echo, which is fine because is exactly the same page.

The question is:

Is there a way to implant html after -for example- press a button in asp.net and show it in the form who will be shown?

At the moment i just add the text to a label, and transform it that way, but i love if i can use some of my web skills here, like for instance, work changing the css using buttons dinamicaly or something like that.

To do something similar to this?:

```
<?php echo '<h2 style="font-weight: 90px">Example</h2>'; ?>
```

or to this hypotetical (and not working) code:

```
someElementInTheToolBoxOfVS2010.Text = "<h2 style='font-weight: 90px'>Example</h2>";
```

The idea is modify dinamicaly the enviroment using css, so, more than "echo" html, i'm intrested on "echo" css, the method the answer post must allow that in some way, shape or form.

Thanks in advance

Note: i'm not really intrested in use the code i shown, it's just for example purposes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977675/what-is-the-asp-net-equivalent-to-phps-echo EDIT** @sebastianForsberg beat me to the punch

Comment: Thanks, i ask you to close this if the CSS element is clear in the other questions. Because this question have that orientation in specific.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JzGfk5r.png