# what to use in asp.net webapi 2 instead of print or echo in php

Tags: php, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write an api that returns some text to a phone system that reads the text.
print with php works but return of type string with asp webapi does not work.
is there anithing like print of php for asp web api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ASP.Net equivalent to PHP's Echo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977675/what-is-the-asp-net-equivalent-to-phps-echo)

Comment: all of the answers are for older versions of asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command

`Response.Write("some text");`